# Convert nvarchar(max) to boolean in sql server R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I convert `nvarchar(MAX)` to `BOOLEAN` in SQL Server R2. I have tried this

```
           Declare @WhereClause nvarchar(max) = 'CityID=1 and CategoryID in(select CategoryID form Category where ParentCategoryID=3';
      select CONVERT(bit, @WhereClause) as Test
```

SQL throw an error like this

```
    Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
    Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'CityID=1 and CategoryID in(select CategoryID form Category where ParentCategoryID=3' to data type bit.
```

I want to use the `@WhereClause` in my where clause in sql query.
I have [go through this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) but I cant find the solution

Comment: You can't have just a WHERE clause dynamic, it's either whole query or none of it.

Comment: I want to have the where clause dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do something like this my friend:

```
DECLARE @CityID AS SMALLINT
DECLARE @ParentCategoryID AS SMALLINT
Declare @WhereClause nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(max)

SET @CityID = 1
SET @ParentCategoryID = 3

SET @WhereClause = 'CityID = ' + CAST(@CityID AS NVARCHAR(10)) +
' and CategoryID in(select CategoryID form Category where ParentCategoryID = '
+CAST(@ParentCategoryID AS NVARCHAR(10)) +')' 

SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE ' + @WhereClause

EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
```

here is **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d3ba/3)** sample.

Comment: when I use `SET @WhereClause = 'CityID = ' + CAST(@CityID AS NVARCHAR(10))` every thing is fine but when I use the remaining part then sql shows `Invalid column name 1` when I pass `@ParentCategoryID = 1`

Comment: If the query works fine when you use `'CityID = ' + CAST(@CityID AS NVARCHAR(10))` there for you are in true way, maybe you need to see the second part of your query more careful.

Answer (score 1):

I dont really understand why you would want to convert it into bit datatype.
However you will not be able to do this in SQL Server:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx

You can use TRUE or FALSE which converts to 1 and 0 respectively, but doesnt work with anything else.

```
Declare @WhereClause nvarchar(max) = 'TRUE'
select convert( bit, @WhereClause) as Test
```

Returns 1